# SSL with Tomcat 7 at Ubuntu: unable to connect

Tags: tomcat, ubuntu, ssl, https

I'm trying to secure my Tomcat 7 Server with SSL. It's runnin on Ubuntu 11.

So first I created a keystore with this command:

```
keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA
```

as password I took 'changeit'

This is my Connector in the server.xml:

`<Connector port="8443" maxThreads="200" scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
keystoreFile="${user.home}/.keystore" keystorePass="changeit" clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />`

so if I try to connect to https//:localhost:8443, I got an error that it's unable to connect.

I have no idea what I have to do. :(

Please help me! Thx :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following attribute to your connector:
`protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"`

I.e.

```
 <Connector protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"
           port="8443" .../>
```

This is **absolutely** required.

Assuming that there is no problem with the keystore this should work.
You could use a java based tool to create your keystore you know e.g. [Certificate Helper](http://sourceforge.net/projects/certhelper/)